# How to achieve 'buy X items get Y items free function'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here I have a table called *Products*:

| id | transaction_id | type | price | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | 350 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | a | 250 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | a | 150 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | a | 100 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | a | 100 | 5 |
| 6 | 1 | a | 50 | 6 |
| 7 | 2 | b | 400 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 | b | 100 | 2 |
| 9 | 2 | b | 60 | 3 |

Requirements: Whenever you buy three 'a' items, the cheapest of the three will be free; Whenever you buy two 'b' items, the cheapest of the two will be free. The results table should be like:

| transaction_id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 800 |
| 2 | 460 |

Explanation: For transaction_id 1, the total cost is: 350+250+100+100=800 (the items whose id == 3 and 6 have become free; For transaction_id 2, the total cost is: 400+60=460 (the item whose id == 8 has become free)

I have no clue about how to select all the free items.

Comment: transaction 2 has no `a` products, why do you apply second rule to it?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the second rule should apply to 'b' items, just edited it.

Comment: do transactions always contain same types? can transaction 1 for example contain a and b products? which product will be free then?

Comment: yes, it is allowed

Comment: If you buy three copies of MySQL Community Edition, you get a fourth copy for free.  :-) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MySQL 8.0+, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function as the following:

```
select transaction_id, sum(discount_price) as price
from
  (
    select transaction_id, 
       case 
           when (type='a' and row_number() over (partition by transaction_id, type order by price desc) % 3=0) 
             or (type='b' and row_number() over (partition by transaction_id, type order by price desc) % 2=0) 
           then 0
           else price 
       end as discount_price
    from table_name
  ) T
group by transaction_id
order by transaction_id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Je_WD66s).

For older versions of MySQL, you can simulate the `ROW_NUMBER()` functionality as the following:

```
set @tid=null;
set @tp=null;
set @rn=0;
select D.transaction_id, sum(D.discount_price) as price
from
   (
     select T.transaction_id, 
       case 
           when (T.type='a' and T.rn % 3=0) 
             or (T.type='b' and T.rn % 2=0) 
           then 0
           else T.price 
       end as discount_price
     from
        (
          select *, 
            if(@tid<> transaction_id or @tp <> type,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn, 
            @tid:=transaction_id, @tp:= type
          from table_name
          order by transaction_id,type, price desc
        ) T
  ) D
group by D.transaction_id
order by D.transaction_id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1c6Ur4LT).

Comment: thank you for your solution. However, If the mysql version is less than 8.0, and it doesn't support window function, then how to solve it?

Comment: You are welcome, I updated the answer for MySQL versions that are less than 8.0.

Comment: Thank you so much for your updates and I almost understand it. However, if we change the promotion rule to: Whenever you buy four 'a' items, the cheapest two of the four will be free; Whenever you buy five 'b' items, the cheapest three of the five will be free.  I am stuck in how to use modulo% operation to solve this new promotion rule.

Comment: *Whenever you buy four 'a' items, the cheapest two of the four will be free*, this will be a bit more complex, I think -not sure- you need to group the items in groups each group contains 4 items. I'll try to provide you with a solution once I have some free time.